# Extracting sections of a string from a string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, templates, extract

I have this string here:

```
var string1 = 'Hello. My name is Bob! I love cats!'
```

I need to extract the name from the string using a template string as a sort of reference.

A template string should look something like this:

```
var extract = 'name is *! I'
```

The function would return ['Bob'] in this case.

The asterisk represents possible values for inputs. I know there could be much better ways to solve this problem but I was wondering if there was a way to do it like that.

Here is an example of an expected output using a different 'template':

```
var extract1 = 'have * kids.'
var string1 = 'I am 32 years old. I have 2 kids.'

extract(string1, extract1) //Should return ['2'] or ['have 2 kids.']

//Or, . . .

var extract1 = 'have * kids.'
var string1 = 'I am 32 years old. I have 1+1 kids.'

extract(string1, extract1) //Should return ['1+1'] or ['have 1+1 kids.']

//An optional delimiter parameter could be passed: extract(str1, str2, '*')
```

Comment: Do you happen to know about [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Comment: Yes, I do but I don't know how they would help to good in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract necessary strings, using RegExp.

If you need to have it as a function that accepts two strings-parameters, you may simply replace (within mask parameter) asterisk (`*`) with `(.*)` to match any number of characters within capturing group and make [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) out of it to [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) against your input string and return first matching substring:

```js
const testStr = 'I am 32 years old. I have 2 kids.',
      ageMask = 'I am * years old',
      childrenMask = 'I have * kids',
      
      extract = (str, mask) => 
        str.match(new RegExp(mask.replace('*', '(.*)')))[1]
        
console.log('Age is: :', extract(testStr, ageMask))        
console.log('Children: :', extract(testStr, childrenMask))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this.

For example, you want to do extraction for

```
var extract1 = 'have * kids.'
var regex = /have .* kids./
var string1 = 'I am 32 years old. I have 2 kids.'
var s = string1.match(regex)
// have 2 kids.

var extract1 = 'have * kids.'
var regex = /have .* kids./
var string1 = 'I am 32 years old. I have 1+1 kids.'
var s = string1.match(regex)
// have 1+1 kids.
```

Comment: I chose Yevgen's answer due to it's slightly better explanation. Thank you.